# Previous template is being rendered. Flask

Tags: python, flask

I was working on a mini project using flask framework. I just finalized that and started a new project. But when I run the project and call the routes of program with local host from browser. it says 404, not found. Even now its not rendering  simple "Hello World" template. But when i use the route of previous program. Then browser renders the previous template. Even without server running.  I'm using pycharm IDE. i  changed IDE and as well as browser ( chrome to edge ) but didn't see the solution.
I request experts for helping me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to troubleshoot:

1. Empty the cash of all browsers
2. Use a new folder for your new project
3. Run your new project in a virtual environnement [tutorial here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html)
4. Check out the paths in yours Flask app config and your Pycharm project settings to make sure they are not pointing to the  old project's folder